# Perl Skip lines without any alphanumeric characters

Tags: regex, perl

Have a tab delimited file I need to parse and I want to skip lines that do not contain any alphanumeric characters.

Every other line in the file contains tab delimited fields that does not contain any data.  So it appears it is a blank line if not for the tabs in the line.

I have tried using next unless line has a alphanumeric character but that is not working
Any thoughts?   Thanks

```
while (defined($line = <IN>)){                  
  chomp($line);
  next unless $line =~ /\w/;
  print OUT "$fields[3]\t$fields[4]\t$fields[5]\t$fields[6]\t$fields[13]\t$fields[15]\t$fields[10]\n";
}
```

Comment: Is this what you're lookign for (http://regex101.com/r/bL1wM7/1)

Comment: I think you're leaving something out, both because `next unless $line =~ /\w/` *should* work, and because there's nothing in here that would populate `@fields`.

Comment: `\w` is actually a word character which matches `_` as well. In case you really mean `[0-9a-zA-Z]`

Comment: or POSIX  `[:alnum:]`

Answer (score 0):

A few lines of input might be helpful to have a few lines of input.  Also are you re-declaring the @field array in the block or is it printing the same set of values over and over again? e.g.

```
while (<$fh>) {                  
  chomp;
  my @fields = split(/\t/, $_, -1);
  print OUT join("\t", map { $fields[$_] } (3,4,5,6,13,15,10)), "\n" if $_ =~ m/\w+/;
}
```

Comment: *A few lines of input might be helpful to have a few lines of input.*  Yeah.  Definitely. ;)

Answer (score 0):

To match a line that contains alphanumeric characters use:

```
.*?[\p{L}\p{Nd}]+.*
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to add some quantity to the \w. Try \w+ instead.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
while (defined($line = <IN>)){                  
  chomp($line);
  next if $line =~ /^\s*$/;
  print OUT "$fields[3]\t$fields[4]\t$fields[5]\t$fields[6]\t$fields[13]\t$fields[15]\t$fields[10]\n";
}
```